# Two linux users with different clocks

Tags: linux, cron

Is it possible to have two linux users with slight delays on their clocks?

The reason I ask is I have two scripts executed by the cron every minute (one on each user). One script copies a file from the another machine the other loads the data in the file into mysql.

We have been finding the loading of the data misses the first minute 90% of the time. I think this is because it is called exactly the same time as the call to copy the file from the other machine is executed.

If I could delay the user clock whose cron executes the loading script by 5 seconds i think this would solve the problem.

Perhaps there is another way of achieving this? Something easier I am missing. I would like the first script to be called every round minute and the second to be called 5seconds after every round minute.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `sleep 5` or `sleep 10` to the start of the cron entry.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best answer to this is to set up `xntp` so the clocks are in sync. Then, as glglgl suggests, put a `sleep` at the top of the script you want delayed.